# How to aggregate sum across three tables?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have four tables like this

Table 1: `MsPatient`

```
PatientID PatientName
PA001    | Danny andrean
PA002    | John Travolta
PA003    | Danny Lee
```

Table 2: `TransactionHeader`

```
TransactionID PatientID TransactionDate
TR001        | PA001   | 2012/12/6
TR002        | PA002   | 2013/11/4
TR003        | PA003   | 2010/4/12
```

Table 3: `TransactionDetail`

```
TransactionID MedicineID Quantity
TR001        |   ME001  | 5 
TR002        |   ME001  | 6
TR003        |   ME002  | 5
```

Table 4: `MsMedicine`

```
MedicineID MedicineName MedicineStock
ME001     |HIVGOD      |100
ME002     |CancerCure  |50
```

How can I show show `PatientID`, `PatientName`, and `TotalMedicineBought` (obtained from the amount of Medicine Quantity purchased) where `MedicineID` of purchased medicine was 'ME001' and `PatientName` consists of 2 words or more.

Example:

```
PatientID | PatientName    | Total Medicine Bought 
PA001     | Danny Andrean  | 5
PA002     | John Travolta  | 6
```

I tried this query:

```
select 
    mp.PatientID,mp.PatientName,SUM(td.Quantity) as TotalMedicineBought 
from 
    MsPatient mp, TransactionDetail td 
inner join 
    TransactionHeader th on th.TransactionID = td.TransactionID 
Group by 
    td.TransactionID, mp.PatientID, mp.PatientName
```

I don't know how to make a condition that consist two words

I use SQL Server 2008

Comment: What is the use of table `TransactionHeader`?

Comment: Also two or more *words *or *characters*? I mean if there is a patient named `abcd` will he come in that criteria or not?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago!). You should especially **not** mix the two styles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the original query is the mixing of different ways of doing joins.  You should avoid commas in the `from` clause.  If you really, really want a `cross join`, then use the `cross join` statement.

Your problem is one of filtering for the right name *and* joining the tables together:

```
select p.PatientID, p.PatientName,
       sum(case when MedicineId = 'ME001' then Quantity else 0
           end) as Total_Medicine_Bought
from MsPatient p join
     TransactionHeader th
     on p.PatientID= th.PatientID join
     TransactionDetail td
     on td.TransactionID =th.TransactionID
where PatientName like '% %'
group by p.PatientID, p.PatientName;
```

This query also shows a good use of aliases.  For readability, these should be abbreviations of the table names, rather than arbitrary letters.  It also shows the use of conditional aggregation.  You should easily be able to see how to modify the query to also show `ME002`, for instance.  Having at least two parts in the patient name seems equivalent to having at least one space.  `like` is a simple mechanism to look for a single space.

Comment: its a good query but the condition which require two words are more,it have bugs..
if the patient name was '  lee',it come in the condition was right

Comment: @projek . . . That is true.  If you have such problems of names starting or ending in spaces, you can use `like '%[^ ][ ]%[^ ]'`.  My suggestion for using `like` is that it is shorter and possibly more portable among databases (I don't think the original question specified the database).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this -:

```
select a.PatientID,a.PatientName,sum(Quantity) Total_Medicine_Bought
from MsPatient a
join TransactionHeader b
on a.PatientID= b.PatientID
join TransactionDetail c
on b.TransactionID =c.TransactionID
where MedicineID='MEOO1' and (Length(a.PatientName) - length(REPLACE(a.PatientName, ' ', '')) + 1)=2
group by a.PatientID,a.PatientName
```

Sql Fiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c2cc/3

Comment: yeah,but lacking the condition that the patient name have to consist two words or more..
like if the patient name only john it wont show,it show only patient name which consist two word like john travolta

Comment: I have edited the sql statement to select only the name consisting two words. If you need more than two words add condition >=2                sql fiddle(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59c70/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select PatientID ,PatientName,sum(td.Quantity)asTotal Medicine Bought from MsPatient mp
inner join TransactionHeader t on  mp.PatientID = t.PatientID 
inner join TransactionDetail td on t.TransactionID =td.TransactionID 
Group by mp.PatientID,mp.PatientName
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. I created the tables with the data from your sample, with 2 additional sets of users and transactions: Bobby Lee Smith and Fred. Based on your requirement that the query only return patients with at least one space in their name, I added the PATINDEX clause. Here is the query:

```
 select p.PatientID, p.PatientName, sum(d.Quantity) as 'Total Medicine Bought'
 from   MsPatient p
 join   TransactionHeader h on p.PatientId = h.PatientId
 join   TransactionDetail d on h.TransactionId = d.TransactionId
 where  PATINDEX('% %', p.PatientName) > 0
 group by p.PatientID, p.PatientName
```

Here are the results:

```
 PatientID      | PatientName      | Total Medicine Bought  
 PA001          | Danny andrean    | 5  
 PA002          | John Travolta    | 6  
 PA003          | Danny Lee        | 5  
 PA004          | Bobby Lee Smith  | 3
```

Removing the PATINDEX:

```
 PatientID      | PatientName      | Total Medicine Bought  
 PA001          | Danny andrean    | 5  
 PA002          | John Travolta    | 6  
 PA003          | Danny Lee        | 5  
 PA004          | Bobby Lee Smith  | 3  
 PA005          | Fred             | 5
```